# Extracting data from a website after a delayed time with PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax, request

I would like to extract prices from [Klipsch.com](http://klipsch.com) but the prices don't immediately load upon loading the site, they load after the website is fully loaded using JavaScript or some other script. For example, I'm trying to extract the price from the inside of [this page](http://www.klipsch.com/products/reference-premiere-home-theater-systems#rp-280) from the inside of this element:

```
<span class="product-display-price ecommerce-element">$3,284.00</span>
```

I've tried using Simple HTML DOM Parser but there is no delay function. I would like to achieve this in PHP but languages like Ajax would work fine too.

Comment: do you have there permission? seems to be a breach of their terms if you dont.

Comment: You need permission just to get prices from a website? I'm not making this go public, I just am using it to see prices over time. @Dagon

Comment: http://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/introduction/getting-permission/#determine_if_permission_is_needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site loads item details from an external javascript file. Why don't you call that file instead?

- `http://product.shopatron.com/product/{product_id}.jsonp?apikey={your_api_key}&...`

For example, http://www.klipsch.com/products/la-scala-ii-floorstanding-speaker calls:

- `http://product.shopatron.com/product/1000996.jsonp?api_key=5gsk5uyr&apiVer=2.4.4&jstVer=2.4.4&method=get&headers%5BAccept%5D=*%2F*&callback=jQuery17202970524297561483_1481065390010&_=1481065390234`

Comment: Haha! Lol I never even thought of that! I might be pretty stupid to not realize that. :P